# На что ссылается this в данном случае?

Tags: javascript, this, scope

```
function Len() {
    this.name = "leno";
    this.age = 24;

    this.every = function () {
        for (let i in this) {
            console.log(this.i)
            debugger
        }
    }
}
```

В дебаггере заметил, что `this` ссылается на функцию-конструктор, а не на объект вызывающий метод. Почему?

Пример использования

```
let len = new Len()
len.every()
```

Comment: 1) Добавьте пример, как вы вызываете `Len()` и на каком этапе `this` неправильный. 2) Тут `this.i` вероятно нужно `this[i]`.

Comment: Добавил. На этапе `this.i`.

Comment: _this ссылается на функцию-конструктор_ - почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: `this[i]` сработал! Однако я не понимаю в чем _сакральное_ отличие между `this.i` и `this[i]`

Comment: В дебаггере `this.i` указывал на Len()

Comment: Хотя это не так. Я неправильно использовал дебаггер, прошу прощения, но все равно не понимаю почему именно `this[i]`

Comment: _сакральное отличие между this.i и this[i]_ - `this.i` - это получение свойства с именем `i`; `this[i]` получение свойства с именем, которое хранится в переменной  `i`

Comment: и если проще, то `this.i` === `this['i']`

Comment: Понял-понял, спасибо большое. Довольно глупая ошибка (даже в среде было отмечено, что `i` не используется). Еще раз, огромная благодарность.